# How to wrap an <ul> in another <ul>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, html-lists, prepend

I have an unordered list that I would like to wrap inside another unordered list in jQuery, using the following code:

```
$('ul.innerlist').prepend('<ul><li>');
$('ul.innerlist').append('</li></ul>');
```

However, rather than the first line creating the opening tags and the second creating closing tags (and wrapping the `.innerlist`), the first line appears to create both open and close tags, resulting in this

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class="innerlist">
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Instead of this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul class="innerlist">
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses [jQuery's `wrap()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap the selected elements with the elements you provide.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/bD8LQ/

```
$('ul.innerlist').wrap('<ul><li></li></ul>');
```

Comment: +1 for implying that a `ul` is not a valid child of another `ul`.

Comment: In the sense I'm using it (a family tree) the nested lists make sense as each child (li) in a family (ul) can have a family of their own

Comment: thanks, as is always the case the actual answer is usually annoyingly simple!

Answer (score 2):

See http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: While this is a valid resource to offer, it doesn't really *answer* the question...although, I know, 'give a man a fish, feed him for a day; teach a man to fish, feed him for a lifetime...'

Comment: I consider my answer an "idea".

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$('ul.innerlist').each(function(i,v){v=$('<ul><li></li></ul>').append(v);});
```

or the `wrap` function.